# How to upload file in PHP and store information in SQLi database?

Tags: php, file, mysqli, upload

So I'm trying to do this file upload, and store information such as the size of the file, name, and URL of it in a database, while having the file just upload to a folder on my computer (for testing purposes). It's uploading no problem, the only issue I'm having is that the information I want isn't getting stored in the database.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$file_name=basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;
$fileSize=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$complete=$file_name.$imageFileType;
$myUrl=$target_dir.$complete;

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
 // Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 10000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $mysqli=connect();
        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_file (file_name,file_title,file_size,file_url) VALUES (?,?,?,?)') or die(mysqli_error());

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_param('ssis',$complete,$file_name,$fileSize,$myUrl);
        $stmt->close();
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.<br>";

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}}
```

It has to be something with the SQL statement, but I just can't see what it is, any ideas?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: There aren't any errors showing up, that's what's making it so confusing for me. I'm running this through Xampp to test, database is all set up, so I don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: `It is not working` Which is not working ? Can you be specific ?

Comment: Have you started error_reporting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have called the bindParameters() method after calling execute().
It should be the other way round.

i.e.

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssis',$complete,$file_name,$fileSize,$myUrl);
$stmt->execute();
```

...

Comment: This is what the issue was, completely forgot bindParameters() goes before the execute, I was thinking of bindResults(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it's the reason that you used the incorrect method to open a new connection to the MySQL server.

You can create a new connection like this:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("dbhost","username","passwd","dbname");
```

or

```
$mysqli=new mysqli();
$mysqli->connect("dbhost","username","passwd","dbname");
```

or

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("dbhost","username","passwd","dbname");
```

In addition,you must bind parameters firstly and then execute the sql.